# Add exchange account to phone via a file or a form

Tags: android, html, settings, exchange-server, account

Is it possible to add a new exchange account to a phone (android OS) via a single config file (like `MMS`) or a `HTML` based form so that when the user opens that file or submits that form, it automatically add the new exchange account to the phone?